# Parameterization before correlation breaks correlation?

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

Whenever I parametrize my HP LoadRunner VUGen script before doing correlation, correlation is broken:

- Design Studio does not find as many suggestions as before parameterization
- Design Studio does not properly replace all instances after pressing "Correlate"
- Manual correlation doest not properly replace all instances as well

Why's that so? Is this a bug?

Example: Our application features a GUID which we use as some kind of "session token". Of course the GUID changes at each run, so we have to correlate it. If I have not parameterized any value yet (e.g. host name) I simply select the GUID -> right click -> correlate and everything is fine. After parameterizing the script if I do the same: it does not replace the GUID everywhere anymore, also the Design Studio finds fewer suggestions for auto-correlation as before.

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example of something that worked and then was broken after parametrezation (copy it from the script)? It is hard to understand from your description what exactly went wrong. Also please mention the version of LoadRuner you are on.

Comment: Version: see tags. I'm adding a concrete example later today!

Comment: The correlation is just an advanced text search. If the parameter is part of a value that needs to be correlated then after parameterezation the value is changed (replaced by parameter name) and the correlation search can no longer find it. I didn't understand from the example if this is the case. If this is not the case please send us the script to LoadRunner feedback (in VuGen -> Help -> Feedback) or open a thread in the LoadRunner support forum (free users forum) and attach the script there so we can check it.

Answer (score -1):

Correlation comes in many forms

- State
- Time
- Session
- Business Process, user parameter dependent

What you are observing here is the last component, where when you change an input an output changes and this alters the returned data in such a way that the correlation previously set is insufficiently distinct to pick up the next dynamic component.

Process-wise, this is easily addressed.  Record the business process several times.   The first two times do not vary the use inputs.  This will allow you to pick up items related to session, state and time and perhaps limited business process data for one data set.   On the third (and perhaps subsequent) recordings, change your user input data, such as login credentials, widget selected from the screen, etc...

Here is a podcast that may help to ground the process

http://www.perfbytes.com/dynamic-data-correlation